# Variable in return function

Tags: javascript

Is any way in Javascript, how access to variable value in return function?

```
function x (){
  return{
    foo:function(text){
      value= text;
    }
  }
}
a=x();
a.foo("some text");
```

Comment: You can't.  You probably want to return it.  Also, you need to declare that variable.

Comment: Assuming it was supposed to be `var value ...`, that's a closure, and you can't access the internal variables of a function enclosed in another function, even if it's in an object.

Answer (score 3):

Since, you haven't declared nowhere the variable `value`, this variable will be declared on the global scope (as a property of the window object in the environment of a browser). So you can access it as below. However, this is **bad practice**, I mean to use a variable without having first declared it. This is called [implied global](http://archive.oreilly.com/pub/a/javascript/excerpts/javascript-good-parts/awful-parts.html).

```js
function x (){
  return{
    foo:function(text){
      value = text;
    }
  }
}
a=x();
a.foo("some text");
document.write(value);
```

Answer (score 3):

My personal opinion would be to use the object orientated approach.

```
var SomeObject = function(){
    var text = "";
    this.setText = function(value){
        text = value;
    };
    this.getText = function(){
        return text;
    };
};

var myObject = new SomeObject();
myObject.setText("This is the text");
alert(myObject.getText());
```